# How to set a background image on a UITableView and have the table view span the full height?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

Currently, I am using a UITableViewController. I'm setting a background image on the table view. I have a custom view which contains a segmented control and a search bar that I am setting as the table view header. I'm styling its background to be transparent so that you can see the background image behind it.

Here's what it looks like so far:

[image]

However, I would like it to look like this, where the white background color of the table view spans the full height:

[image]

How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *views = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
views.image = [UIImage new];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = views;
```

Comment: Try above code.. Is this what you are talking about?

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't these steps solve your problem ?

- remove the tableview background image;
- set the tableview background color to white;
- add the background image to the table view header instead.

Comment: I think the problem is that I don't want the image to follow the scroll. So when I add the image to the header, it is follows the header as it scrolls. If I pull down to refresh, you see a white background instead of the image.

Comment: Oh, ok. I guess one (ugly) way to do it would be to add a white footer, with a height high enough for the underlying image to never appear (ie. footer height > screen height). But that's pretty hacky.

Comment: Heh, yeah that would be kinda hacky. Also, I don't know how easily I would be able to calculate the height.